# jquery insert js variable into php function

Tags: php, jquery, variables, insert

I want to insert js variable into my php function in javascript.

JS:

```
function moderator_activity(who){
 var getIt = <?php echo json_encode(moderatorActivity()); ?>;
}
```

I want to make something like that:

```
var getIt = <?php echo json_encode(moderatorActivity(who)); ?>;
```

where "who" is js variable.

I tried to do:

```
var getIt = <?php echo json_encode(moderatorActivity(?>who<?)); ?>;
```

but i got:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
```

I don't want to make another file with php function so that's why i combined it :)

I hope you understand.

Comment: php and javascript run in different environments at different times. What you are trying can't be done. Explain your use case

Comment: That is just not possible. JS runs on the browser, PHP on the server side.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm getting value from mysql which I want to show in html. I has got event in pagination <a onclick="moderator_activity('<? echo $row['name']; ?>');">Next</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you create a file named `script.php`, use can use PHP to change the MIME of the document, using the `header` PHP function.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/javascript"); ?>

window.onload=function(){
  console.log('<?php echo "Using PHP!"; ?>');
}
```

Although this data isn't interchangeable because it's generated server-side, this is the best you're going to get.

You would include it on you website, something like:

```
<script src="script.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

As a better alternative, you could try something with Ajax.

Comment: I tried with json and I guess it's the best way to do what I want, but thanks for your reply.

Comment: Alright, you should accept the answer anyways because it solves the question regarding the post.  Thanks.